# Will `removeLast` ever reduce the capacity of an array in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I know that `.append` will occasionally increase the capacity of an array and form a new copy of the array, but will `.removeLast` ever reverse this and reduce the capacity of an array by copying into a new smaller array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No (or at least if it is yes, it is a bug (*)). That would violate its complexity promise.

If you read the complexity promise for `append`, it reads:

> Complexity: Amortized O(1) over many additions. If the array uses a bridged NSArray instance as its storage, the efficiency is unspecified.

"Amortized O(1) over many additions" means that for any given operation it may not be O(1), but the limit as the number of elements goes towards infinity is O(1) because larger and larger pre-allocations will be made, and so reallocations will become more and more infrequent.

Now read the complexity promise for `removeLast()`:

> Complexity: O(1)

There's nowhere for a reallocation to hide in there (or at the very least it could not be implemented "by copying into a new smaller array").

(*) There's a difficult exception to this. Any mutation on an Array is subject to possible copy-on-write. That means that *any* mutation, no matter its performance promises, may become O(n) if it shares storage with another Array. This makes reasoning about Swift performance very challenging, but is not specific to this question.

Answer (score 2):

As Rob Napier's answer points out, no, `removeFirst` should not reduce the capacity of the array. Adding some details, `removeLast` doesn't either, and `removeAll` *does by default*, though it takes a parameter `keepingCapacity` to change that behavior.

```
var arr = [Int]()
print(arr.capacity)    // 0
arr.append(1)
print(arr.capacity)    // 2
arr.append(2)
print(arr.capacity)    // 2
arr.removeFirst()
print(arr.capacity)    // 2
arr.removeLast()
print(arr.capacity)    // 2 (though the array is now empty)
arr.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
print(arr.capacity)    // 2
arr.removeAll()
print(arr.capacity)    // 0
```